Display resolution stretches over display since updating to 24.10
I've updated to Ubuntu 24.10 this week. Since doing so, I'm having an issue with my display resolution on my primary external display.
The display is an AOC U2790PQ, which is equipped with a 4K (3840 x 2160) panel. Prior to updating and using 24.04, this resolution was shown without problems. Now, that resolution is still correctly shown in the Settings > Display section for this display. Upon selecting it however, it stretches further as the display. The bottom and right side of the desktop, are not in view. The highest resolution that is completely shown is 2880 x 1620, going higher results in a desktop that stretches further as the actual display size.
There is no error message given when I switch to the displays native 4k resolution, it just doesn't show completely.
The AOC display has two display modes, 1:1 and wide. The wide one stretches whatever resolution is displayed to the display, but in this case, it doesn't constrain it. The 1:1 shows the resolution within it's own maximum 4k resolution, in a box. When selecting the 4k resolution however, it shows the 2880 x 1620 box, with black edges around it, in which the 4k resolution stretches over the size of that box, but not outside of that box.
This problem didn't occur when using 24.04, it started after updating.
I'm using Ubuntu on a Lenovo Thinkpad z13 Gen 2, with AMD Ryzen 7 PRO 7840U and AMD Radeon 780M .

I encountered a similar issue after upgrading. I realized that the refresh rate changed to 60Hz even if this is not supported by my monitor at 4k resolution (reading the specs, this seems to apply to your monitor as well).
If this is indeed the case, try the "External Only" screen mode after setting the refresh rate of the external screen to 30Hz.

Thank you for your reply. There's no option to set my display to 30Hz, it's either 59.97 or 59.96Hz showing for this display in my settings. I don't know if 'External Only' is a setting as well, if so then I do not see that either. I'm using the external display with the lid closed and then the laptop display doesn't show up in my list of Displays, so I assume it's external display only then.
